# TLS Certificates only for Clients

Tags: tls, certificates, x.509

I'm aware that sites like StartSSL use Client-Certificates, I opened mine in Firefox and it showed me: "SSL-Client-Certificate", "E-Mail-Receiver-Certificate", "E-Mail-Signer-Certificate".

Now I'm asking myself, for self-signed certificates, is it possible to restrict usage of X.509(v3?) certificates to be only TLS-Client? (-> no server / no S/MIME)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for X.509 to be only "TLS client" (actually to have the *extended key usage* only set to *client*). I suggest you to take a look at [XCA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/), it is free a graphical tool which will allow to easily create and manage certificates (it is actually a small PKI).

You will then be able to visually see all the main options a certificate can have, which one fits in the client or server template profiles, and play with these options.